# Addition operation in angular2 using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, addition

I wrote a component like below:

```
export class AppComponent {
    public num1: number = 2;
    public num2: number = 3;
    public sum: number = 0;
    public add() {
        this.sum = this.num1 + this.num2;
    }
}
```

For this, I'm getting sum as 23 instead of 5. Give me a proper solution to do addition.
I will be glad to know the answer

Comment: I don't see any problems here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZE9MuIQKQaUUc39ptJ5u?p=preview

Comment: See Nitzan Tomer's answer for why your TypeScript variables declared as numbers can be treated as strings:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269701/typescript-trying-the-addition-of-two-variables-but-get-the-concatenation-of-t

Answer (score 5):

this is because your numbers are being treated as strings.

so its doing "2" + "3" = "23"

to force a number use parseInt function or do ...

```
this.sum = +this.num1 + +this.num2;
```

or this should work too ...

```
this.sum = +this.num1 + this.num2;
```

Comment: According to the question, they aren't strings.

Comment: The question has most likely not the full code. I would expect the same reason that's provided in the answer.

Comment: isNaN("2") === false